# Pandas Group by three columns but retain all other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like this:

```
offer_id  affiliate_id affiliate_source affiliate_sub5  advertiser_id Payout_cent Revenue_cents
 428572          1327         14331605       14331605            291    50             30
 428572          1327             1465           1465            291    50             30
 428572          1327             1336           1336            291    50             30
 428572          1327         14331605       14331605            291    50             30
 428572          1327         14331605       14331605            291    50             30
```

I am grouping three columns "offer_id", "affiliate_id", "affiliate_source"

Operation:

```
df1.groupby(['offer_id', 'affiliate_id', 'affiliate_source'])[["payout_cents", "revenue_cents"]].sum()
```

Result:

```
offer_id affiliate_id affiliate_source                      payout_cents    revenue_cents
428572   1327         14331605                               90            150
                      1465                                   30            50
                      1336                                   30            50
```

**Issue:
I need to get other columns also like "advertiser_id" and "affiliate_sub5" after group operation.**

Thanks.

Comment: In that sum there might be several (different) advertiser_id's. Which one do you want? If they are all the same, you can add them to the grouping columns.

Comment: Yes, they are different. So I need to group by advertiser id too?

Comment: No, if they are different you either have to select one of them for each group (the first one, the minimum one etc) or you can go with jezrael's approach and produce a DataFrame which is the same length as the original one.

Comment: Great question! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
cols = ['offer_id', 'affiliate_id', 'affiliate_source']
df2 = df1.groupby(cols)[["payout_cents", "revenue_cents"]].sum().add_suffix('_sum')
df = df1.join(df2, on=cols)

print (df)
   offer_id  affiliate_id  affiliate_source  affiliate_sub5  advertiser_id  \
0    428572          1327          14331605        14331605            291   
1    428572          1327              1465            1465            291   
2    428572          1327              1336            1336            291   
3    428572          1327          14331605        14331605            291   
4    428572          1327          14331605        14331605            291   

   payout_cents  revenue_cents  payout_cents_sum  revenue_cents_sum  
0            50             30               150                 90  
1            50             30                50                 30  
2            50             30                50                 30  
3            50             30               150                 90  
4            50             30               150                 90
```

Another solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
cols = ['offer_id', 'affiliate_id', 'affiliate_source']
cols1 = ["payout_cents", "revenue_cents"]

df1[['{}_sum'.format(x) for x in cols1]] = df1.groupby(cols)[cols1].transform('sum')
```

Answer (score 0):

Then use them in `groupby()`:

```
df1.groupby(['offer_id', 'affiliate_id', 'affiliate_source', 'advertiser_id', 'affiliate_sub5'])[["payout_cents", "revenue_cents"]].sum()
```

Comment: I want to group by three columns not all columns.